# multiple count rows based on date ranges (access db)

Tags: database, ms-access, count

I can get a single count row from a specified date range like this:

```
SELECT table.[EVENT NAME], Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM table
WHERE [EVENT]='alphabetical' And table.DATE>=#11/20/2010# And (table.DATE)<=#11/26/2010#
GROUP BY table.[EVENT NAME];
```

but how could I add multiple rows with different date ranges?

`[EVENT NAME],[DATE 11/20-11/26],[DATE 11/27-12/3], etc...`

---

***EDIT***

the data would look something like this

```
event1;1/11/2010
event1;1/11/2010
event2;1/11/2010
event2;1/11/2010
event2;1/11/2010
event3;1/11/2010
event1;1/12/2010
event1;1/12/2010
event2;1/12/2010
event2;1/12/2010
event4;1/12/2010
event4;1/12/2010
```

etc.

and would like something like this (preferably with more columns) :

```
event1;2;2
event2;3;2
event3;1;0
event4;0;2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a group by clause and group by the date.

You didn't provide example records with expected results, that helps us help you :).
In other words post more information..
But from what I can tell you want a count based on a date range.

So if you had 1/1/2010 with 10 rows
and 1/2/2010 with 20 referenced rows
and 1/3/2010 with 6 reference rows...you'd want output like this:

`1/1/2010 10`

`1/2/2010 20`

`1/3/2010 6`

So `SELECT COUNT(*), MyDate FROM MyTable GROUP BY MyDate`

To answer your question about a date range, think of how group by works, it works by grouping a set of data by combining all sets that match a criteria.  So when you say group by date it groups by a single date.  You want a date range, so each row should know about or understand a range (Start to End).  So you need to include these columns in each of your rows by generating them via SQL.

**Edit**

For instance

`SELECT Count(*), DATEADD(day, -10, GetDate()) AS StartDate, DATEADD(day, 10, GetDate()) AS EndDate
FROM MyTable GROUP BY StartDate, EndDate`

Access has similiar functions to add days to dates so look that up for MS Access.  Then just generate a start and end date for each column.

Comment: how would I group by date ranges?

Comment: @Daniel, You would group by date ranges see this http://www.sqlteam.com/article/group-by-using-weeks

Comment: the part I'm confused about is how do I get two separate groupings, one for event type and another for the date. Or would it be best to build a table that groups events/day and query that for date ranges second?

Comment: @Daniel - When you say event type, do you mean like BirthdayParty, New Years Eve, etc?  If so just add it to your groupings list.  Remember you can group by as many fields as you want as long as it makes sense.  You know your data more then I do.  So first you group by your event type then by your date range.  But remember order matters here, if you group by your date range and then by your event  type you will have the same event come up maybe more then once depending on the data in the table.  For instance an event can come up more then once.  If on the othr hand you group by event continued

Comment: first then you will get a unique amount of events...so you know your data, test it in a query get the results and look at the results.  If they make sense you are good to go.  My incliniation is you want to first group by your daterange then by the event.  `SELECT YourFields FROM YourTable GROUP BY YourStart, YourEndDate, YourEvent`

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I did end up using a pivot with a custom function (fStartofWeek) (http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/862565-dynamic-weekly-date-range-crosstab-report)